# Jquery positioning nav doesn't seem to work on initial load?

Tags: jquery, position

The nav bar is meant to sit at the bottom of the image on page load, but it occasionally seems to just sit in the middle of the image.

Any idea why – it's completely baffling me?!? The site is live at http://thomas-rogers.co.uk/BleepBleeps2/index.html.

```
    Javascript
    $(function() {

var pause = 100; // will only process code within delay(function() { ... }) every 100ms.

$(window).resize(function() {

    delay(function() {

        var width = $(window).width();

        $(document).ready(function() {  
            var stickyNavTop = $('.navigation').offset().top;  

            var stickyNav = function(){  
            /*var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

            if  (scrollTop > stickyNavTop + 5) {   
                $('.navigation').addClass('sticky');  
            } else {  
                $('.navigation').removeClass('sticky');   
            }  */

            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var viewport_h = $(window).height();
            var hero_h = $('.hero-image').height() + $('.hero-image').offset().top;
            var offset = $(window).width()>464?60:0;

            if (scrollTop + viewport_h < hero_h) {
                $('.navigation').addClass('stickynav').css({top:viewport_h-60});
            } else {
                if (scrollTop > hero_h - offset) {
                    $('.navigation').addClass('stickynav').css({top:0});
                } else {
                    $('.navigation').removeClass('stickynav').css({top:hero_h-offset});
                }
            }

            };


            stickyNav();  

            $(window).scroll(function() {  
                stickyNav();  
            });  
            }); 

    }, pause );

});

$(window).resize();

   });

    nav {
background: #fff;
height: 3em;
    }

    nav.navigation {
position: absolute;
padding-top: 1em;
padding-bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
opacity: 0.8;
bottom: 143px;
z-index: 99;
    }

    nav.stickynav {
position: fixed;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
nav.navigation {
    bottom: 80px;
}
    }

    .sticky {
position: fixed !important;
top: 0;
    }

    .sticky2 {
position: fixed !important;
left: 50%;
margin-left: 10px;
top: 11px;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.sticky {
position: relative; !important;
    }

.sticky2 {
    display: none !important;
}
    } 

    HTML
    <header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="eight columns offset-by-eight" id="logo-box">
        <h1 class="logo">BleepBleeps</h1>
        <h3 class="subheader">A family of little friends<br>that make parenting easier</h3>
    <!-- MAILCHIMP SIGNUP -->
        <form action="http://bleepbleeps.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=e6067eec57&amp;id=7e02f5f7e4" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Your email" class="required email mc-field-group" id="mce-EMAIL">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="tooltip my-custom-theme" title="Sign up to receive amazing Bleep Bleeps content!">

            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
        </form><!-- end MAILCHIMP SIGNUP -->
    </div><!-- end logo-box -->
</div><!-- end container -->


<div class="hero">
    <img class="hero-image" src="images/bb-background2.jpg" alt="BleepBleeps Family">
</div>


<nav class="navigation">
    <div class="container">
    <a href="#top"><img src="images/bb_note.gif" alt="bleepbleeps icon" class="notes"></a>
        <ul class="socialnav">
            <li class="circle-social tw"><a href="http://twitter.com/BleepBleeps" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="circle-social fb"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/BleepBleeps" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="circle-social tu"><a href="http://bleepbleeps.tumblr.com" target="_blank"></a></li>
            <li class="circle-social in"><a href="http://instagram.com/bleepbleeps" target="_blank"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

</header>
```

Would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: post relevant code here most of us have 56k connection

Comment: Sorry @roasted, updated with code. Didn't know if it was easier in the browser. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use `$('.hero-image').height()` when the image is complete loaded, in `$(document).ready()` is probably not loaded yet.

So, better use:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //your code
   $('.hero-image').height()
   //your code
});
```

> The document ready event executes already when the HTML-Document is loaded and the DOM is ready, even if all the graphics haven’t loaded yet.
>
> The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images

Comment: Hi Michael, Sorry, I'm really new to javascript (well front-end dev in general) so I'm not too sure what you mean by the above. Do I have to remove any lines of code from my javascript?

Comment: @TomRogers no, just replace: $(function() { by $(window).load(function(){ and see what's going on

Comment: It seems to have worked! Thank you so much! Really appreciate the help, there is so much to learn!